# How can I calibrate the tilting sensor on Android

Tags: calibration, sensors

I have an Android mobile which seems to be of Samsung, or at least a clone thereof. I got it for my wife as a present, so I don't really know which one. Under the battery pack it says "Model: 19502"

when I look through the menus there are absolutely no identifications as to which it is and the settings only allow rather high level stuff, like setting background images, and similar, but nothing system relevant.

When I play games I noticed that the tilt is not correct, so I installed "App Sensor Box" which allows me to test the sensors. It shows a board with a ball on it, and I can see that the ball rolls off when I keep it balanced. Unfortunately this app doesn't allow me to calibrate it, so I wanted to know if such an app exists, or what I can do to calibrate it, because there are not setting to trigger this. The apps I found on Play Store all seem to just read, but don't change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a tough one to answer, as I'm not sure what version of Android you are running, and you have stated it may be a clone.

**Method 1:**

Open "Settings"

Find "Motion" and tap on it

Scroll down the menu and tap on "Sensitivity Setting"

Open "Gyroscope calibration"

Place device on a level surface and tap Calibrate

**Method 2:**

Download 'G-Sensor' from the Samsung Apps store pre-installed on your device.  [Here is a weblink.](http://www.samsungdownloads.net/search_results.html?type=all&search_field=gyro+sensor+calibration+android+app)

**Method 3:**

Download  [Bubble Level](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.androgames.level&hl=en)  from the Google Play store, this has a calibration option also.

Comment: There are no settings as far as I can see, which is very annoying. I try the other suggestions and report back then. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't think there would be settings, that seems to have disappeared on newer versions of Android. Don't forget to put the phone on something perfectly level before calibrating. If none of the above work, I'll see what else I can dig up!

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly with that Bubble Level App. Exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: For German Users, you should look for "Wasserwaage" in the Play Store.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: The bubble app does not work for the Galaxy Tab 3. I'm downloading "G-Sensor" now to see if that works.

Comment: I don't know about method 1 (never owned an Android device with a calibration setting menu, and I got quite a number of them...), but method 2 and method 3 are bound not to work. Unless they are leveraging some root-access feature, there's no single functionality in the Android api that allow to calibrate the sensors (and all apps claiming otherwise are fads)

Comment: Looks like Bubble Level uses accelerometer instead of Gyro

Comment: All mobile device compasses and magnetometers are constantly gathering data and recalibrating themselves. The best way to calibrate them is to provide them with enough data of the magnetic field around them. You do this by rotating your phone by 360º around all 3 axis. Essentially this is what all apps ask you to do. There is no api neither on android or on iOS because this is done by the hardware and there is no need to interfere with it, just give it enough data by pointing your phone at all possible directions. I'd gladly post an answer but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanis: I wish... I can't count the number of times I turned and flipped my device going through a dozen fake 'callibrate accelerometer' apps. Still getting into 'portrait' requires to set it completely vertically, and the 'bubble level' app shows it thinks it's flat, when it's roughly 45 degrees from flat. Tilt minimally sideways, goes into 'portrait' Set it on a flat surface and the screen flips upside-down.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the first answer ...

Method 1 - There is no calibration setting on my Samsung Galaxy S5.

Method 2 - Search the Google Play Store for "Accelerometer Calibration Free" for a specific calibration app, the link in the older answer is dead.

Method 3 - "Bubble Level" works fine and coped with portrait and landscape orientation OK and has a simple calibration option

Additional Method 4 - Search for "Just a Compass" on the Google Play Store for a very detailed compass with a calibration option

Additional Method 5 - Use the calibration option in Google Maps.

*Open the Google Maps app, wait for the blue device location icon to show. Tap the location icon to bring up more information about your location. At the bottom there is the “Calibrate Compass” button.*