# Movement (gyro) input reversed on Zopo 998

Tags: settings, gyroscope

I have Zopo 998 on Android KitKat, and I have started to use cardboard for movies and VR. My problem is that the movement sensors seem reversed: when I turn my head right, the view moves left, and also happen for up and down.

I have tried many applications and such which all behave the same. Nothing in settings that I can find.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Might be a stupid thing, but the first coming to my mind (admitting to never having used that hardware): have you tried to rotate the entire thing by 180°? I'm not even sure whether that's possible – but sometimes it's the easy things... ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yeah tried that and everything acts the same. Even with auto rotate turned off. Very frustrating bug.

Comment: Yuck – sorry. Yeah, would have been too easy. And no, I won't suggest turning your entire body 180° next ;) An idea might be trying to re-calibrate the sensors: [How can I calibrate the tilting sensor on Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/59532/16575) / [How to calibrate G-sensor in Android - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7bD-tPr7i8)

Comment: HaHa, tried hanging my head off the bed...What makes things really odd is the the bubble applications all work correct. It's the VR SBS applications that are reversed. At first I thought maybe just one or two apps but seems they all act backwards.

Comment: And, did the "hangover" work out? :D For the rest, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas then. Might be a "borked SDK" (with a bug for your device). Asking the devs cannot hurt I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and it doesn't look good so far. It's a bug which is model specific. The Zopo 998 is known for this issue (fixed in the 999 model). Perks have been asking for a ROM to correct the error.

Going to just have to keep my eyes open for some fix.

Comment: For more information, please refer to [how to merge account?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)